How can i find the source code of a specific shader node?
Using mix rgb node with the "Darken" option i can't understand why with different inputs we get different results (both wrong result)
i explain better:
Darken is a COMMUTATIVE function so changing the layer order does not change the result. Indeed:
The darken blending mode take every of the tree parameter of the color and compare it to the other 3 parameters of the other color and takes wathever color value is minor
For example: putting as first layer: red(0.5, 0, 0, 1) rgba color
second layer: blue(0, 0, 0.5, 1) rgba color
the output is red, but it should be black (0, 0, 0, 1) as photo below:

Wheter if i swith layer the output is blue:

While if u do this in photoshop, it always gives u back black as it should be:

even if u change layer, the output is the same as it should be:


What does the MixRGB or Mix Shader node factor do exactly? and first link there in comments: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/57013e2a44e974d307f08f41793d810a49537f96/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/material.c#L1525

Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off-topic here,. However, asking directly about X is encouraged. If you can, please edit your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than asking for some external resource, so it can be reopened.

"Darken is a COMMUTATIVE function" - only when factor = 100%
