cant understand why "darken" blending mode not works correctly in the mix rgb shader node - possible bug
Using mix rgb node with the "Darken" option i can't understand why with different inputs we get different results (both wrong result)
i explain better:
Darken is a COMMUTATIVE function so changing the layer order does not change the result. Indeed:
The darken blending mode take every of the tree parameter of the color and compare it to the other 3 parameters of the other color and takes wathever color value is minor
For example: putting as first layer: red(0.5, 0, 0, 1) rgba color
second layer: blue(0, 0, 0.5, 1) rgba color
the output is red, but it should be black (0, 0, 0, 1) as photo below:

Wheter if i swith layer the output is blue:

While if u do this in photoshop, it always gives u back black as it should be:

even if u change layer, the output is the same as it should be:

even if i dont put the BSDF in the shader flow, it doesnt change the output


Haven't you asked this already here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/324777/107598 Set Factor to 1.0 and the result will be black.
